# Transient analysis of LM741 does not work when Rf= 22k ohms

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

As you can see if you run the circuit below it will not work or just simulate very very slow and it does not give any errors. I am very confused because I tried Rf to be 10kohms 47kohms 100kohms 4.7kohms and 1kohms and they all work perfectly EXCEPT 22kohms.
[LM741 PSPICE Model](https://www.ti.com/product/LM741?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=asc-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-soas&utm_content=LM741&ds_k=LM741&DCM=yes&gclid=Cj0KCQiApb2bBhDYARIsAChHC9t8flwPWkc69n-HF3NinpnGrN7hY8TM8kgC5M37auUYxT4R1JMCLCgaArJ-EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image]

---

EDIT:
So I solved the problem I posted but before I explain what I did I will just clarify my post because it may seem to be lacking some information. But if you want to see the fix just scroll down to the FIX section.

So after doing the circuit with a simulation command below

[image]

The .raw screen or that black scope where you can see traces of your signal looks something like this.

[image]

As you can see it just does not finish simulating the circuit immediately.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work". There are numerous ways of not working and they don't all have the same cause.

Comment: Sorry I was not very specific but what I mean by not working is after clicking the run button the .raw screen appears it just simulates very slow and it seems to just simulate forever so I just clicked the halt button after 20 minutes. I am just very confused because we made this exact circuit in a different PC and same thing happens. Note that we did not copy the file but entirely made it again in a different PC.

Comment: I had to add to my reply that this circuit will only simulate fast if Rf is not equal to 22k ohms

Comment: saladlord - Hi, From your update, it seems you have solved this yourself. Please remove the solution that you added to the question (answers don't belong in a *question* in Stack Exchange), then [write your own answer](/help/self-answer) to explain the solution (I see you have just done that), wait 48 hours from the time you first asked the question (system prevents you áccepting a self-answer any sooner), and then you can [áccept an answer](/help/accepted-answer) (yours or a better one, if posted by then) to indicate what solved your problem & effectively close the question. Thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you I am just new to posting questions and after editing my solution to the question and posting it I immediately saw that "Answer your question" button below

Comment: @saladlord - Thanks for the update. Please remember to come back and áccept your answer after 48 hours (or a better one, if posted by then) to indicate what solved your problem & effectively close the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX:
I just changed the simulation command and placed a 0.1m value in maximum timestep. And as you can see in the background LTspice simulated the circuit very fast. Not sure how this works but I'll just research on how timesteps work in LTspice.
[image]

Comment: That's bizarre. Setting a maximum timestep should not have affected the simulation time other than potentially making it longer.

Comment: Before delving into simulations of circuits you should take time to verify that the model works properly. TI's opamps do not always behave well. I'd recommend `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp3*` with tweaked parameters whenevr you need to simulate opamps. In the vast majority of the cases they can fill in the shoes of their competitors, while being 99.9% guaranteed to converge. Also, you can accept your own answer (the green check mark).

Comment: The thought of a downloaded model having a few bugs never really came into my mind so thank you for telling me that and that may help me in the future when building a lot more complicated circuits

Answer (score 1):

I tried your circuit with a 22k feedback resistor and get the same issue where it takes a long time to solve. Changing the integration method does not help.

Apparently, the circuit is oscillating. Placing a 1pF capacitor across the feedback resistor is enough to make the circuit behave and solve quickly.

Comment: I tried changing the maximum time step to 0.1m or 1m and it seems to work just fine. But when the maximum time step is 1u it just simulates very slowly just like my original problem. Currently have no idea why this happens and why this only happens if Rf = 22k ohms.

Comment: @saladlord If the circuit oscillates, the auto-time step will become very small which increases the total solve time. Placing a capacitor across Rf, as mentioned in the above post, will kill the oscillation and the circuit will solve quickly using the auto-time step.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I will keep this in mind and revisit when dealing with this kind of circuits